# How to write a SQL statement which takes multiple where clauses from an associative array input?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a map as a input and wanted to use that mapping in sql where clause.
Example,
I have a table data like,

```
ColA ColB ColC
---------------
A    1   abc
B    2   xyz
C    3   jkf
A    3   asf
B    4   dfa
```

and I've mapping as {A->1, B->2}

Now I want to fire query like,

```
SELECT * from TABLE where KEY = map{key}
```

but I don't know how can I use my map in above query and I don't want call this query multiple times.

I can do it like, 
for key in map:

```
select * from table where key = map[key]
```

but want to do it in one database call.
Expected result is

```
ColA ColB ColC
---------------
A    1   abc
B    2   xyz
```

Comment: `SELECT * from TABLE t join map m on m.key = t.key` ? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Add the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Using the map build `table valued constructor`

```
select * 
from (values ('A',1),('B',2)) tc (Col1A,ColB)
```

Now you can join the above result with your table

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable Y
       JOIN (VALUES ('A',1),
                    ('B',2)) tc (Col1A, ColB)
         ON Y.Col1A = Tc.Col1A
            AND Y.Col1B = Tc.Col1B
```